# Gravity Points not working properly with other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's this awesome codepen called [Gravity Points](http://codepen.io/akm2/pen/rHIsa) which I liked very much and wanted to use on my next project but it turns out it only works well if it is the only element on the page. Once you start adding content above and below it, it miscalculates the mouse position.

Take a look at [my fork here](http://codepen.io/VeeK727/pen/dYqapv), I've added the content above it. Notice if the canvas is aligned perfectly with the screen, the gravity points are created in the right spot but if you click on the canvas when you're half way scrolled up, the points are created a few pixels down.

I'm not great with javascript and jquery, although I'm able to understand which functions it's calling and which functions are being used to draw the points but I can't understand where the calculations are happening and how it's related to scroll position. This functions seems to be triggered when left clicked but where does the cursor coordinates come from?

```
function mouseDown(e) {
        for (var i = gravities.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (gravities[i].isMouseOver) {
                gravities[i].startDrag(mouse);
                return;
            }
        }
        gravities.push(new GravityPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY, G_POINT_RADIUS, {
            particles: particles,
            gravities: gravities
        }));
    }
```

So can someone take a look at it and give some insights?

Comment: The cursor coords come from `e` parameter (short for event)

Comment: This is the code that calls the function: `canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);`. Now how does this send coordinates to `mouseDown` and where does it gets them from?

Comment: you need to get the position relative to the canvas's bounding rect. one way is `var rect =canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); var x = mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left; var y= mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top;`

Comment: I'm trying to understand the same thing from [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/). Can you please guide me how this code can fit into the js file on codepen? Can you create a fork?

Comment: unfortunatly I'm in China rn and google.api is blocked here so I can't test it on your code, but this should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<canvas>` element has its own coordinate system, which differs from the document one (the one sent by mouseEvents).
What you need to do is to check canvas's bounding box and remove its offset to your mouseEvents coordinates :

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(mouseEvent){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); 
  var x = mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left; 
  var y = mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top;
  // doSomething with x and y
  for (var i = gravities.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (gravities[i].isMouseOver) {
      gravities[i].startDrag(mouse);
      return;
     }
   }
  gravities.push(new GravityPoint(x, y, G_POINT_RADIUS, {
    particles: particles,
    gravities: gravities
   }));
}
```

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks a lot. I modified the `mouseDown` function to include the first 3 lines of code in your function and passed x, y to `GravityPoints`. Thanks a ton mate